# My timers shouldn’t be clickable when the minute is done

Tags: ios, swift

I’m using time pickers and they work correctly as expected but the problem that i dont want to user to reserve a past time. when i click on the time pickers they doesn’t allow me to reserve past time but the problem is when i leave it opened and time continues it allow me to choose past time which is the time i click on it for example i opened time picker at 10:11 when i leave time picker opened and its 10:12 it allow me to choose 10:11 which is in past. when 10:11 is done it shouldn’t be clickable. Hope its clear and this is my code if you can help

````
 func createTimePicker() {
       
       StartTimeTxt.textAlignment = .center
       EndTimeTxt.textAlignment = .center
       
       //tool bar
       let toolbar = UIToolbar()
       toolbar.sizeToFit()
       
       //bar button(
       let doneBtn = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .done, target: nil, action: #selector(donePressed))
       toolbar.setItems([doneBtn], animated: true)
       
       //assign tool bar
       StartTimeTxt.inputAccessoryView = toolbar
       EndTimeTxt.inputAccessoryView = toolbar
       
       // assign time picker to the txt field
       StartTimeTxt.inputView = StartTimePicker
       EndTimeTxt.inputView = EndTimePicker
       
       
       let calendar = Calendar.current
       //First range
       let startTime = Date()
       let startRangeEnd = calendar.date(byAdding: DateComponents(minute: 30), to: startTime)!
       let startRange = startTime...startRangeEnd
       //Second range
       let endTime = calendar.date(byAdding: DateComponents(minute: 1), to: startRangeEnd)!
       let endRangeEnd = calendar.startOfDay(for: calendar.date(byAdding: DateComponents(day: 1), to: startTime)!)
       let endRange = endTime...endRangeEnd
       StartTimePicker.date = startTime
       StartTimePicker.minimumDate = startTime
       StartTimePicker.maximumDate = startRangeEnd
       EndTimePicker.date = endTime
       EndTimePicker.minimumDate = endTime
       EndTimePicker.maximumDate = endRangeEnd
       if #available(iOS 13.4, *)  {
           StartTimePicker.preferredDatePickerStyle = .wheels
           EndTimePicker.preferredDatePickerStyle = .wheels
       }
   } ```
````

Comment: In the completion block, add a check to see if selected time < current time?

Comment: what do you mean by completion block .. sorry I’m a beginner

Comment: What happens when the user presses the done button? The action executed is what I'm talking about

Comment: when u click done we store the start and end time, but i want if the minute is done it be disabled to click

Comment: That is more advanced requirement, I think you would need to create a timer that checks the current time periodically and updates minimumDate of the picker when a new minute has been reached. A much simpler solution is as already suggested to wait until the button is pressed and then validate the input and either display an error alert or quietly adjust the select start time if it is in the past.

Comment: ok i like this solution. i already have donePressed function. what should i add to force the start time to be current time if its less than the current time?